# Determinant using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

The following code generates a 3x3 matrix in terms of x,y,z. I want to generate the determinant of the matrix. But unable to do so.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from sympy.matrices import Matrix
x,y,z =sp.symbols('x,y,z')
H1=np.array([[x,y,z]])
H2=np.array([[0.0630,0.0314,-0.0001],[0.0314,96.1659,-0.0001],[-0.0001,-0.0001,0.0001]])
H3=H1.T
H=H1*H2*H3
print H
```

To find the determinant of the above matrix, I am using the following command.

```
H.det()
```

But it is showing error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'det'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You first need to convert your numpy n-dimensional array to a sympy matrix, and then perform the calculation of the symbolic determinant. What @hildensia said won't work, because `H` is a numpy object, which won't work with symbolic entities.

```
>>> M = sp.Matrix(H)
>>> M
Matrix([
[ 0.063*x**2,   0.0314*x*y, -0.0001*x*z],
[ 0.0314*x*y, 96.1659*y**2, -0.0001*y*z],
[-0.0001*x*z,  -0.0001*y*z, 0.0001*z**2]])
>>> M.det()
0.000604784913*x**2*y**2*z**2
```

Comment: Glad to hear. What about [your older sympy related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4053821+[sympy]+hasaccepted%3Ano), are those solved too?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I don't remember clearly enough to tell you whether they were addressed positively. If they were not, I would have reposted anyway. =D

Comment: There's really no reason to use a numpy array in the first place if you have symbolic entries.

Comment: @asmeurer, That's true, but perhaps the OP has specific reasons for first performing some calculations in numpy (speed, result of a complex simulation, ..). That's not for me to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant in numpy is not a member of the array class but a function in the `linalg` module. So simply use:

```
np.linalg.det(H)
```

Comment: With the above command, I am getting TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Comment: I get `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc det`.